# An orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix with real spectra. Is it true that since the spectrum of $U$ is $\{-1,1\}$, so $U^{2}$ is similar to the identity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- The only matrix similar to the identity matrix is the identity matrix.  For any invertible $P$, $PIP^{-1} = I$.
- If $U$ is any diagonalizable matrix with spectrum $\{1,-1\}$, then $U^2 = I$.  One way to see this is by noting that $U$ would have minimal polynomial $x^2 - 1$.
- All orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ by the spectral theorem for normal matrices

All together: if $U$ is a real orthogonal matrix with a real spectrum, then $U$ is diagonalizable with spectrum (a subset of) $\{-1,1\}$ and $U^2 = I$.

Comment: Thanks. By the spectral theorem, is orthogonal matrix over complex space? I thank you if it is explained.

Comment: Thanks. By the spectral theorem, is the orthogonal matrix diagonalizable over complex space? I thank you if it is explained.

Comment: Yes, that's right: orthogonal matrices are normal, and therefore diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$